# Problems running init as part of yii 2 install

Tags: mamp, yii2, mcrypt, mamp-pro

I am installing yii 2 on a mac. I have mamp pro (3.0.7.3 latest) when i go to the command line and run.

php init i get a message saying

The mcrypt PHP extension is required by Yii2.

I checked the server using phpinfo()  and it shows mcypt enabled.  I checked the php.ini and it is listed and the file exists in the referenced directory.

any ideas anyone ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This probably means that your php CLI (Command Line Interface) does not use the same `php.ini` than MAMP. You could use something like `php -c /path/to/mamp/php.ini` to be sure to use the same php.ini.

Or try the following command : `php --ini`, this will show you configuration file names, e.g. :

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /path/to/php/conf
Loaded Configuration File: (none)
```

You could then make a symbolic link :

```
cd /path/to/php/conf
sudo ln -s /path/to/mamp/php.ini php.ini
```

Comment: Thanks that was the problem... I tried the php -c /path/php.ini init.  Now the framework is objecting to module version on mamp being newer so I'll have to figure that one out..